# How can I remove all variables defined by `cmake -D` at once?

Tags: c++, cmake

How can I remove all variables defined by `cmake -D` at once?

For example, I defined `FOO` and `BAR` using:

```
cmake -DFOO=foo -DBAR=bar
```

Errors occur when I run `cmake -U* ../`,

```
CMake Error: File /Modules/CMakeSystem.cmake.in does not exist.
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:186 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

- **How can I remove all variables defined by the `-D` option at once?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `cmake -D` command line option to define cache variables, they are placed in the `CMakeCache.txt` file, along with all of the other CMake-defined cache variables. To list all of the cached variables, you can run `cmake -LAH`. The variables prefixed with `CMAKE_` are set and used internally by CMake. When you run:

```
cmake -U* ..
```

you remove **all** of the cached variables, including these crucial `CMAKE_` variables. This leaves your CMake project build in a *broken* state. The documentation for the [`cmake -U`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) option even warns about this:

> Use with care, you can make your `CMakeCache.txt` non-working.

---

There is no special method to remove only those cached variables manually defined by the user via the `cmake -D` option. You have to remove them individually:

```
cmake -U FOO -U BAR ..
```

or, you can open the `CMakeCache.txt` file, and manually delete them from the file.

Another alternative would be to simply delete the `CMakeCache.txt` file altogether, which will run CMake on your project from scratch.

I recommend adding a common prefix to your `-D` command line variables (such as `MYVAR_`).

```
cmake -D MYVAR_FOO=foo -D MYVAR_BAR=bar ..
```

This way, they are neatly grouped when viewed in the CMake GUI, and you can safely delete all of them from the cache using a `-U` globbing expression:

```
cmake -U MYVAR_* ..
```